# fllashMessenger() not found in controller says phpStorm but is working

Tags: php, zend-framework, zf3

I'm getting an error in phpStorm in the ZF3 controller classes with the message:

```
Method 'flashMessenger' not found in ...Controller
```

At the same time it is working like a charm. But I would like this IDE not found error to be removed anyway.

The application was updated to `ZF3` and I installed the flash messenger plugin found on [Zendframework GitHub](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-mvc-plugin-flashmessenger)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because controller plugins aren't methods on the class, but classes themselves returned in the controller's `__call` method.

This means that the PhpStorm 'Undefined method' PHP inspection can't see the method in the class.  It can be disabled in the settings under Editor -> Inspections -> PHP, but this will obviously stop the inspection from identifying actual errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following above the line to silence the inspection for that one line of code:

```
/** @noinspection PhpUndefinedMethodInspection */
```